# HighCharts column unknown number of series

Tags: javascript, highcharts, asp-classic

I'm trying to populate a HighCharts dataset with results from SQL Server in Classic ASP. 
When the number of series is known everything work OK but I can't get it work correctly for unknown number of series.
Here is my code for 4 series - 1 line and 3 columns.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $(function () {
       var DivName1 = '<%= DivName(1)%>'
       var DivName2 = '<%= DivName(2)%>'
       var DivName3 = '<%= DivName(3)%>'
       var DivName4 = '<%= DivName(4)%>'                    

       var DivN1 = parseInt('<%= DivN(1)%>')
       var DivN2 = parseInt('<%= DivN(2)%>')
       var DivN3 = parseInt('<%= DivN(3)%>')
       var DivN4 = parseInt('<%= DivN(4)%>')                 

       var DivTotal1 = parseFloat('<%= DivTotal(1)%>')
       var DivTotal2 = parseFloat('<%= DivTotal(2)%>')
       var DivTotal3 = parseFloat('<%= DivTotal(3)%>')
       var DivTotal4 = parseFloat('<%= DivTotal(4)%>')



       $('#DivCompTotalA').highcharts({
           chart: {
               type: 'column'
           },
           title: {
               text: ''
           },
           credits: {
               enabled: false
           },
           legend: {
               layout: 'vertical',
               align: 'right',
               verticalAlign: 'top',
               itemWidth: 180,
               useHTML: true,
               x: 0,
               y: 40,
               borderWidth: 0
           },
           xAxis: {
               categories: ['']

           },
           yAxis: {
               max: 7.01,
               labels: {
                   enabled: false
               },
               gridLineColor: 'transparent',

               plotLines: [{

                   value: DivTotal1,
                   color: '#333333',
                   width: 2,

                   label: {
                       text: 'Org.=' + DivTotal1 + '<br>N=' + DivN1,
                       align: 'right',
                       y: -5,
                       x: 0,
                       style: {
                           fontSize: '13px'
                       }
                   },
                   zIndex: 2
               }],
               title: {
                   text: ''
               }

           },

           plotOptions: {
               column: {
                   pointPadding: 0.2,
                   groupPadding: 0.10,
                   borderWidth: 0
               },
               series: {
                   dataLabels: {

                       enabled: true,
                       y: 5,
                       style: {
                            fontSize: '14px'
                        }
                   },
                   enableMouseTracking: false,
                   events: {
                       legendItemClick: function () {
                           return false;
                       }
                   }
               }
           },


           series: [{
               name: DivName2 + ' [' + DivN2 + ']',
               color: '#c9e7ff',
               data: [DivTotal2]
           }, {
               name: DivName3 + ' [' + DivN3 + ']',
               color: '#4898a4',
               data: [DivTotal3]
           }, {
               name: DivName4 + ' [' + DivN4 + ']',
               color: '#ffd949',
               data: [DivTotal4]
           }]
       });
   });
```

My first question is How to replace these lines:

```
var DivName1 = '<%= DivName(1)%>'
var DivName2 = '<%= DivName(2)%>'
var DivName3 = '<%= DivName(3)%>'
var DivName4 = '<%= DivName(4)%>'
```

with a loop I tried this loop but with no success

```
var N = '<%=N %>'
    var DivName = []
    for (var i = 0; i <= N; i++) {
        DivName[i] = '<%= DivName(i)%>';
    }
```

How to write the "i" inside the '<%= DivName(i)%>' so it will be a variant

Comment: Why you cannot check a length of DivName collection/array. Then use loop to prepare correct structure?

Comment: I think my problem is with the  series loop syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

Set series to nothing:

```
series: []
```

Fill it by script (where seriesData is array of prepared data. For format check [documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series)

```
$.each(Div, function(i){
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    if (chart.series.length === 1) {
        chart.addSeries({
            name: Div[i].Name + i + ' [' + Div[i].N + ']',
            color: '#c9e7ff',
            data: Div[i].Total
        });
    }
});
```

Here an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/chart-addseries/) how to add 1 series. You can add as many as you like with each loop.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
    });

    // the button handler
    $('#button').click(function () {
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        if (chart.series.length === 1) {
            chart.addSeries({
                data: [194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4]
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I saw this example, but may be I too newbie to adjust it to my needs.

Comment: First I did not how to keep my chart syntax/design 
   
    name: DivName2 + ' [' + DivN2 + ']',
    color: '#c9e7ff',
    data: [DivTotal2]
           }

second I did not how to do it without the button.

Comment: @SarahO. to implement this code you just need to add it to your function after you set highcharts options. I've updated example to be closer to your case (you still need to prepare array with data). If you could provide example on fiddle with input - it will be easier to help you

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but It still not working for me

Comment: @SarahO. I've made an example for you http://jsfiddle.net/4smpdsyh/2/ I hope it will make sence

Comment: Thank you @alexander-stepchkov it make sense. I'll try to implement it in my project

Comment: @SarahO. if my answer help you feel free to mark it as answer ;)

Comment: sorry for my late response and thank you @alexander-stepchkov for your effort. I'm still struggling with this challenge